# How to get the # in some sorted group using SQL and PHP

Tags: php, sql

Scenario:

I have a table with games stats called `gamesstats`.

I am given a team (for me the important part is the id), the league and the sesason.

Now I could check what games did the team play using my games stats by asking only those where the league and the season are as given and the home team id or visitor team id are the team id I've been given.

From that I can get the games where that team played and ask by the `HomeStat` and the `VisitorStat` the stats of this game for that home or visitor team respectively. Then I average them and get the picture about that team.

Now the question:

How do I build this three arrays: An array for the teams averages (easy, done), an array for the league averages (easy, just don't restrict team id), and an array for the # in league the team is on that specific parameter (like is it 4th in the league (by all teams averages) in doing 2 points shots).

A bit of sql so you'll understand how it looks:

```
SELECT \"All Games\" as Flag, count(*) as Games, avg(s.P2M) as P2M, avg(s.P2A) as P2A,  100*avg(s.P2M)/avg(s.P2A) as P2P,
        avg(s.P3M) as P3M, avg(s.P3A) as P3A,  100*avg(s.P3M)/avg(s.P3A) as P3P,
        avg(s.FTM) as FTM, avg(s.FTA) as FTA,  100*avg(s.FTM)/avg(s.FTA) as FTP,
        avg(s.OFFENSE) as OFFENSE, avg(s.DEF) as DEF, avg(s.TOT) as TOT, 
        avg(s.AST) as AST, avg(s.TO) as TurnO, avg(s.ST) as ST, avg(s.FV) as FV, avg(s.CM) as CM, avg(s.PTS) as PTS,
        (avg(s.TOT) + avg(s.AST) + avg(s.ST) + avg(s.PTS) + avg(s.P2M) + avg(s.P3M) + avg(s.FTM) + avg(s.RV) + avg(s.FV))
        - (avg(s.TO) + avg(s.P3A) + avg(s.P3A) + avg(s.FTA) + avg(s.AG) + avg(s.CM)) as EFF
        FROM gamesstats AS gs, stats AS s
        WHERE gs.$homeOrVisitor = s.ID
        AND gs.HomeTeamID = $ESCteam
        AND gs.SeasonStart = $ESCseason
        AND gs.LeagueID = $ESCleague
```

I would prefer a fast solution because we are talking about huge tables (30k+ stats).
Will edit if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I didn't really understand what you really want as you are saying that everything is "easy done". But I can advice you a bit about making your SQL faster. You should not use so much AVG() calls in your SQL. Just select all *distinct* AVG()'s that you need and then just calculate all other values in PHP. For example you should select avg(s.P3M) as P3M, avg(s.P3A) as P3A in SQL, but calculate P3P AS $row['P3P']=100*$row['P3M']/$row['P3A']; in php, and all that AVG() sum's too. PHP is much more easy to scale then MySql, and it will work faster too.

UPD: If you are asking how to get the row position in selection by some field - just select COUNT() of all rows that have bigger value of that field and add "1".

Comment: Not everything is easily done, just the two first things. I still can't do the third, # in league.

Comment: This should give you the idea: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT AVG(something) AS avg_smthing FROM `gamesstats` WHERE LeagueId = $ESCleague AND SeasonStart = $ESCseason GROUP BY HomeTeamId) AS tbl 
 WHERE avg_smthing > (SELECT AVG(something) FROM `gamesstats` WHERE LeagueId = $ESCleague AND SeasonStart = $ESCseason AND HomeTeamId = $ESCteam);

Comment: How to select all distinct avg? that would help me.